# Google Play Store information mixing up Beta and Production versions

Tags: android, publishing

The production release of my app (version 1.4.1) was published on 10 September. On 23 October I uploaded a version (2.0.0) to Beta. Today I downloaded the app from Google Play Store and the version was 2.0.0, i.e. the Beta version.

This is part of the information shown:

[image]

The text underneath What's New shows the information provided for the Beta upload. The text underneath Current Version shows the correct version number of the Production release.

I'm confused by the mixing up of information and don't understand why the Beta version is available for download. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet, but is it a closed beta and are you logged in to an account that is enlisted in the beta when viewing the play store listing? If you haven't yet try logging out of the play store, or looking at it from an account that doesn't have beta access and then check if it shows the beta app when you search it.

Comment: I thought of that and deleted all testers for Beta but I still got the same problem. However, after your answer I went to Google Play with a different browser in which I am not logged into Google and the correct information is displayed. The mixed up information shown in the question was confusing the issue.